# Exchange 2010 Blocking Twitter

Tags: email, powershell, exchange, twitter

I am responsible for a windows network with an Exchange 2010 server.  It appears that we haven't been receiving twitter emails for quite sometime, maybe even as far back as just before Halloween/November.  Does anybody know how one would properly whitelist Twitter or check emails that were bounced directly?  Here's part of a Mark from PowerShell (this doesn't work):

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ContentFilterConfig

Name                                  : ContentFilterConfig
RejectionResponse                     : Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering.
OutlookEmailPostmarkValidationEnabled : True
BypassedRecipients                    : {}
QuarantineMailbox                     :
SCLRejectThreshold                    : 7
SCLRejectEnabled                      : False
SCLDeleteThreshold                    : 9
SCLDeleteEnabled                      : False
SCLQuarantineThreshold                : 9
SCLQuarantineEnabled                  : False
BypassedSenders                       : {}
BypassedSenderDomains                 : {twitter.com}
Enabled                               : True
ExternalMailEnabled                   : True
InternalMailEnabled                   : False
ExchangeVersion                       : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
Identity                              : ContentFilterConfig
ObjectCategory                        : private.local/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Message-Hygiene-Content-Filter-Config
ObjectClass                           : {top, msExchAgent, msExchMessageHygieneContentFilterConfig}
WhenChanged                           : 1/8/2014 8:53:15 AM
WhenCreated                           : 9/27/2011 8:48:45 PM
WhenChangedUTC                        : 1/8/2014 1:53:15 PM
WhenCreatedUTC                        : 9/28/2011 12:48:45 AM
IsValid                               : True
```

Comment: Okay I added *.twitter.com as well.

Comment: What version of Powershell are you running?

Comment: Do you only have an Exchange server or is there a spam filter/gateway in front of Exchange as well?  If only Exchange, what do the message tracking logs show?

Comment: I'm running version 2.0.  I'm pretty sure we have no hardware filter/gateway. I'm not sure if we have a software solution, where would I look?  We have a SonicWALL, but I'm in the process of trying to update the firmware, it's so old and it doesn't have any email spam blocking subscriptions.